# SortedSet to a seq preserving the (sorted) order

Tags: scala, seq, sortedset

I have a `SortedSet` and I need to convert it to a `Seq` while preserving the order (because I need to call `map` with a seq output).

A couple of tests in the REPL shows that `toSeq` keep the order as well as `toIndexedSeq` but I need to be sure: is it guaranteed to keep the order?

Otherwise I can use `.toSeq.sorted` but that is seriously overkill...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions such as `toSeq` are implemented by building a new collection (for toSeq it is a mutable `Buffer`) and added the elements in the iteration order of the original collection (the `SortedSet`). That means that the resulting sequence will always be ordered.

Comment: indeed, the implementation keep the order (basically the code is `{ this.foreach(buffer += _); buffer}`. And `SortedSet.foreach` and `Buffer +=` preserve the order. I would have prefer if it was guarantied by the API though